# CSS Style in SAS: Outside Double Border on Table

Tags: html, css, templates, sas, border

The snippet below actually produces a table similar to what I want when it runs here, but the output RTF file shows a different table without the inside borders. How could this be?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta name="Generator" content="SAS Software Version 9.3, see www.sas.com">
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>SAS Output</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.table {
 color: #000000;
 font-family: 'Arial', 'Arial';
 font-size: 10pt;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: normal;
 border: medium double black;
 }
.proctitle{
 color: #000000;
 font-family: Arial, 'Albany AMT', Arial;
 font-size: x-small;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: bold;
 }
.systemtitle{
 font-family: Arial, 'Albany AMT', Arial;
 font-size: large;
 font-weight: 14pt;
 color: black;
 }
.header, .rowheader, .footer, .rowfooter{
 color: black;
 font-size: 10pt;
 font-family: Arial, 'Albany AMT', Arial;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 padding: 10px;
 }
.data{
 font-size: 10pt;
 font-family: Arial, 'Albany AMT', Arial;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 padding: 10px;
 }
.l {text-align: left }
.c {text-align: center }
.r {text-align: right }
.d {text-align: right }
.j {text-align: justify }
.t {vertical-align: top }
.m {vertical-align: middle }
.b {vertical-align: bottom }
TD, TH {vertical-align: top }
.stacked_cell{padding: 0 }
-->
</style>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!-- 
function startup(){

}
function shutdown(){

}

//-->
</script>

</head>
<body onload="startup()" onunload="shutdown()" class="body">

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!-- 
var _info = navigator.userAgent
var _ie = (_info.indexOf("MSIE") > 0
          && _info.indexOf("Win") > 0
          && _info.indexOf("Windows 3.1") < 0);
var _ie64 = _info.indexOf("x64") > 0

//-->
</script>

<div class="branch">
<a name="IDX"></a>
<table class="systitleandfootercontainer" width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" rules="none" frame="void" border="0" summary="Page Layout">
<tr>
<td class="c systemtitle">Example Title Here</td>
</tr>
</table><br>
<div>
<div align="center">
<table class="table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" rules="all" frame="box" bordercolor="#C1C1C1" summary="Procedure Print: Data Set WORK.TEST">
<colgroup>
<col>
<col>
</colgroup>
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="l header" scope="col">CAR</th>
<th class="r header" scope="col">YEAR</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="l data">FORD</td>
<td class="r data">1995</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="l data">HONDA</td>
<td class="r data">1998</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="l data">CHEVY</td>
<td class="r data">2001</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
<br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

However, this produces a table as such:

[image]

I'd like for it to look like:

[image]

I created the following dataset and used `ODS RTF` and my custom `.css` file (in this example, called TESTFOX) to output the table:

```
DATA TEST;
    INPUT CAR $10. YEAR;
    DATALINES;
    FORD    1995
    HONDA   1998
    CHEVY   2001
    ;
RUN;

ODS RTF FILE="C:\USERS\DOCUMENTS\TEST.RTF" CSSSTYLE='C:\USERS\DOCUMENTS\TESTFOX.CSS';
PROC PRINT DATA=TEST NOOBS;
RUN;
ODS _ALL_ CLOSE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `nth child` selector. Css below may work depending on your html structure.

```css
tr:first-child {
  border-top: medium double black;
}
tr:first-child {
  border-bottom: medium double black;
}
td:first-child {
  border-left: medium double black;
}
td:last-child {
  border-right: medium double black;
}
```

**EDIT**

After the original poster added some details, here is a possible way to get the inner border.

```
td, th {
    border: thin solid black;
}
```

Comment: The code I presented is the entire structure. I see what the `nth child` is trying to do but I'm not quite sure how to embed the code. It doesn't work by adding periods like `.tr` and `.td` and appending to the entire code.

Comment: I'm just using Notepad++ to edit the code above which is a .css file, and then I'm using SAS to call in this .css file to style an output table. I don't think there is an HTML code if that makes sense?

Comment: @Foxer In your results window in SAS, you should be able to right-click on it and choose 'View HTML Source' (or something similar).

Comment: @RobertPenridge The code is like 1500 lines so I pasted the first few lines to show how it is structured. After which, the code begins as I have shown above beginning with `.table {`. Will this help?

Comment: @Foxer It's a step in the right direction, but we'd need just the relevant parts of the HTML.  Specifically, the HTML source for the table you are trying to format, and then the definitions of any CSS styles that the table uses.

Comment: @Foxer @RobertPenridge yes it will be really helpful to us (and essentially yourself) if you'd be able to share the html table snippets, since their html structures can vary. It should start with the tag `<table>` and ends with `</table>`

Comment: @DPac I've attached the code, and the snippet actually appears as I want it (except it doesn't look like Arial font), but using it with ODS RTF there is still the same problem with no inside borders.

Comment: @Foxer could you please try adding the css I just posted as edit?

Comment: @DPac It still doesn't produce the inside borders.